# Djoser: Password Reset with Username

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have developed an app using Django. It uses Djoser for user authentication.

Problem:
I have allowed user to register with already existing email addresses i.e. there might be multiple users using same email ID. So I can't reset password with the email field.
Either I must use username only or the combination of username and email.

How can I do this?

Note:- Using base endpoint `/users/reset_password/` but it requires email only to reset the password.

Comment: first, having different users with same user email is a very bad idea. You should change that. You could validate if the email exists before taking any new registration . Second, it is very straight forward, if you can validate like I said on  the first line than you can reset the pass using email only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add another field to djoser **SendEmailResetSerializer**.
and perform additional validation in **SendEmailResetSerializer.get_user method** or validate method.

example:

1. In settings file add the path to a custom SendEmailResetSerializer.

```
DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'password_reset': 'path.to.CustomSendEmailResetSerializer',
    },
}
```

2. Define the custom serializer (inherit from djoser SendEmailResetSerializer.) and add a field, username for example.

```
class CustomSendEmailResetSerializer(SendEmailResetSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

3. Perform additional validation in get_user method or validate method.

```
class CustomSendEmailResetSerializer(SendEmailResetSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def get_user(self, is_active=True):
        # Retrieve user here.
        return user
```